# how to display hidden divs one by one fading in and out

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

i have this html code

```
<div class="container" id="container">
<div class="post"><h1>first title</h1>description here</div>
<div class="post"><h1>second title</h1>description here</div>
<div class="post"><h1>third title</h1>description here</div>
</div>
```

and this css

```
.container {
height: 200px;
width: 300px;
border: 1px solid #666;
position: relative;
}
.post {
padding: 5px;
height: 190px;
width: 290px;
position: absolute;
z-index: 0;
}
```

and this js

```
// JavaScript Document
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(".post").css("display","none");
        $(".post:first").fadeIn(1000).css("display","block");


setInterval("displayPosts()",6000);

//document ready end
});


function displayPosts(){

}
```

guess now you know what i need i really don't understand how to animate them one by one every 6 seconds i know how to do that with images but it's not working with text at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".post").css("display","none").first().fadeIn(1000);
   setInterval(displayPosts, 6000);
});


function displayPosts(){
   $(".post:visible").fadeOut(1000, function(){
        $(".post").eq(($(this).index() + 1)%3).fadeIn(1000);
   })
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dv9kA/3/)**

Answer (score 3):

I know there are already three answers but I thought I should post my solution too. I think a loop is not necessary:

```
$(".post").hide();

(f=function(){
    $(".post:hidden:first").fadeIn(1000, f);
})();
```

This is pretty much self explanatory:

- the first line basically hides the div on load (*always* display the content for accessibility reasons)
- find the first hidden `.post`
- fade it in over one second
- repeat

The above would go in `$(document).ready(...);` as usual.

I also made a jsfiddle with the above: http://jsfiddle.net/ninty9notout/nzPrV/

And you can see this in action on this: http://mark.james.name/

Good luck

Comment: thanks a lot may be that's not what i was looking or but i really needed this code so bad thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [delay](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) function to delay an animation in the queue.

```
$(".post").each(function(i) {
    $(this).delay(i * 6000).fadeIn(6000);
});

// And to fade out
$(".post").each(function(i) {
    $(this).delay(i * 6000).fadeOut(6000);
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/5Cd6j/)

Answer (score 1):

```
/*

¤ How to Use ¤
    Javascript:
    $(".boxes").loadsequence();

    HTML:
    <div class=".boxes">A</div>
    <div class=".boxes">B</div>
    <div class=".boxes">C</div>


¤ Options ¤  
    delay: [200]          //Change loading speed

*/


(function ($) {
    $.fn.loadsequence = function (options) {

        //Define Parameters
        var defaults = {
            delay: 300
        };

        //Merge Default with Passed options
        var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

        //Caching $(this) for speed
        var obj = $(this).hide();

        //Start at item 0
        var i = 0;
        LoadSequence();

        //recursive for all the items.
        function LoadSequence() {
            obj.eq(i++).fadeIn(options.delay, LoadSequence);
        };

    };
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() {

    //setup function to run animations
    function displayPosts(){
        if (current < $posts.length) {
            $posts.eq(current).fadeIn(1000);
            current++;
        } else {

            //if all the elements have been animated we can cancel the interval by calling `clearInterval` on our timer variable (which holds a reference to the `setInterval` we called earlier
            clearInterval(timer);
        }
    }

    //cache the `.post` elements and set their `display` CSS property to `none`, also set a counter for the current animation
    var $posts  = $('.post').css("display","none"),
        current = 0;

    //set an interval to run the animations every six seconds
    var timer = setInterval(displayPosts, 6000);//run on interval

    //run animation function on `document.ready`
    displayPosts();
//document ready end
});
```

It's a good idea to pass the `setInterval` function a function name or an anonymous function that runs other functions inside it, if you pass it a string of a function name then `eval` has to be used (which in this case **is** evil since you don't have to do it).